# selecting max date in range, excluding multiple other date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, filter, date-range

my first time posting.

I have a tricky task of finding the latest date within a range, but excluding multiple other date ranges.  I have code that *does work*, but it seems awfully taxing.

I am selecting the **MAX(Date)** within a range.  However, I have a table, **bfShow**, where each show has its own date-range (stored as **DateStart** and **DateEnd**).  So I need the **MAX(Date)** within the range which does *NOT* have a show on that date (there may be 0 to 99 shows overlapping my date-range).

Note: I have **dbo.fnSeqDates** which works great (found via Google) and returns all dates within a range - makes for very fast filling in 6/1/12, 6/2/12, 6/3/12...6/30/12, etc.

What I'm doing (below) is creating a table with all the dates (within range) in it, then find all the Shows within that range (#ShowIDs) and iterate through those shows, one at a time, deleting all those dates (from #DateRange).  Ultimately, #DateRange is left with only "empty" dates.  Thus, the MAX(Date) remaining in #DateRange is my last date in the month without a show.

Again, my code below *does work*, but there's got to be a better way.  Thoughts?

Thank you,
Todd

```
CREATE procedure spLastEmptyDate
    @DateStart date
  , @DateEnd   date
as
begin

   -- VARS...
   declare @ShowID    int
   declare @EmptyDate date

   -- TEMP TABLE...
   create table #DateRange(dDate date)
   create table #ShowIDs(ShowID int)

   -- LOAD ALL DATES IN RANGE (THIS MONTH-ISH)...
   insert into #DateRange(dDate)
   select SeqDate
   from dbo.fnSeqDates(@DateStart, @DateEnd)

   -- LOAD ALL SHOW IDs IN RANGE (THIS MONTH-IS)...
   insert into #ShowIDs(ShowID)
   select s.ShowID
   from bfShow s
   where s.DateStart = @DateStart

   -- PRIME SHOW ID...
   set @ShowID = 0
   select @ShowID = min(ShowID)
   from #ShowIDs

   -- RUN THRU ALL, REMOVING DATES AS WE GO...
   while (@ShowID > 0)
   begin
      -- REMOVE FROM TEMP...
      delete DR
      from #DateRange DR
         , bfShow s
      where DR.dDate between s.DateStart and s.DateEnd
        and s.ShowID = @ShowID

      -- DROP THAT ONE FROM TEMP...
      delete from #ShowIDs
      where ShowID = @ShowID

      -- GET NEXT ID...
      set @ShowID = 0
      select @ShowID = min(ShowID)
      from #ShowIDs
   end

   -- GET LAST EMPTY SPOT...
   select @EmptyDate = max(dDate)
   from #DateRange

   -- CLEAN UP...
   drop table #DateRange
   drop table #ShowIDs

   -- RETURN DATA...
   select @EmptyDate as LastEmptyDateInRange

end
```

Comment: I assume this is SQL Server 2008 or later (given the `date` datatype)? Also, it appears that all shows start on the same date (because you're selecting `s.DateStart = @DateStart`) - is that correct? Some worked example(s) would also be helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us know what version of SQL Server you're on because that will help determine your options, but you should be able to use the BETWEEN operator in a JOIN between the fnSeqDates function (it's a table-valued function, so you can join to it directly rather than inserting them into a temp table) and the bfShow tables:

```
SELECT TOP 1 tDate.SeqDate
FROM dbo.fnSeqDates('6/1/2012', '6/30/2012') tDate
    LEFT JOIN bfShow tShow
        ON tDate.SeqDate BETWEEN tShow.DateStart AND tShow.DateEnd
WHERE tShow.ShowID IS NULL -- no matches found
ORDER BY tDate.SeqDate DESC -- to pull the most recent date
```

Comment: Awesome.  Short and sweet and intuitive.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I thought I'd re-phrase the question, and try to expose some edge cases. I'm not using your function at all. If this isn't right, can you give an example where it fails?

```
create table bfShow (
    DateStart date,
    DateEnd date
)
go
CREATE procedure spLastEmptyDate
    @DateStart date
  , @DateEnd   date
as
    --Return @DateEnd, or, if that is within a show, find the contiguous
    --region of shows covering it, and select the day before that
    ;with ShowsCovering as (
        select DateStart,DateEnd from bfShow where DateStart <= @DateEnd and DateEnd >= @DateEnd
        union all
        select s1.DateStart,s2.DateEnd
        from
            bfShow s1
                inner join
            ShowsCovering s2
                on
                    s1.DateStart < s2.DateStart and
                    (
                        --This join would be helped by an indexed computed column on bfShow, either Start-1 or End+1
                        s1.DateEnd >= s2.DateStart or
                        s1.DateEnd = DATEADD(day,-1,s2.DateStart)
                    )
        where
            s2.DateStart > @DateStart
    ), Earliest as (
        select MIN(DateStart) as MinDate from ShowsCovering
    )
    --1) If there are no rows, the answer is @DateEnd
    --2) If there are rows, and the MIN(DateStart) = @DateStart, then no day exists
    --3) Otherwise, the answer is MIN(DateStart)-1
    , Answer as (
        select @DateEnd as Result where exists(select * from Earliest where MinDate is null)
        union all
        select DATEADD(day,-1,MinDate) from Earliest where MinDate > @DateStart
    )
    select Result from Answer
go
insert into bfShow(DateStart,DateEnd)
values ('20120601','20120612'),
('20120619','20120630')
go
exec spLastEmptyDate '20120601','20120625'
--Result = 2012-06-18
go
exec spLastEmptyDate '20120525','20120625'
--Result = 2012-06-18
go
exec spLastEmptyDate '20120601','20120705'
--Result = 2012-07-05
go
insert into bfShow(DateStart,DateEnd)
values ('20120613','20120618')
go
exec spLastEmptyDate '20120601','20120625'
--Result - no rows
```

---

By the way, in your current solution, these lines:

```
drop table #DateRange
drop table #ShowIDs
```

Are unnecessary. Temp tables created within a stored procedure are automatically dropped when the stored procedure exits. So you can avoid the little dance at the end and make the last line just `select max(dDate) as LastEmptyDateInRange from #DateRange`, if you want to continue using your solution.

Comment: Damien thank you for letting me know about the drop #tables - I'll drop that line from now on.

Comment: Just note that it can bite you when you're developing the proc in the first place: they remain until the connection is closed, so if your code errors and you fix/re-run, that temp table might still exist and give you an error. Minor, but can get annoying.